# Is it possible to remove mondodb.lock files, .wt files, etc. from computer?

Tags: mongodb

Hoping somebody might have some tips. I was doing a LinkedIn Learning class that included a project with MongoDB. The exercise files they provided included some of the database files. I am now trying to delete these, which include index files, collection files, .wt extensions and the .lock files. However, every time I delete them they simply reappear on my computer. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you should not delete any of the data files by yourself without a MongoDB support team's guidance. If you want to delete any databases _or_ collections use any of the tools like `mongo` shell, Compass GUI, a programming language, etc. These tools allow query the installation for databases, collections , indexes _and_ also work with them (e.g., delete).

Comment: So the thing is that I'm not running MongoDB at all. I have no intent on running it and just want the files gone.

Comment: May be you can just unnstall the MongoDB (you can destroy all the data, then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need your database anymore:

- Stop MongoDB.
- Uninstall MongoDB.
- If any files are left over, manually delete them.